# Angular 4 + Spring Boot + Spring Security- store session on Angular side

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

My previous app was based on Template Engine(Velocity) and spring security. It was easy to manage resources, check logged users etc. Now i would like to build my fronted with angular. Angular needs to be run on the another port 4200 using CLI, spring runs on 8080. I am not sure about when we should use REST Api with token authentication and when use Session. I found information that session is using with web app where connection is good enough to keep connection with server but Rest Api, as so Angular as fronted framework, is often used when connection isnt stable(so we cannot hold session). The session enables us identifier users and obtains access to resource. I could not find and step by step tutorial or something useful which could exaplain how angular could store session given by Spring Security and how to do it. Any explanation or helpful links to resources about how works session would be appreciated. The most important thing to me is how i can configure or even if i can do the same app with Angular which i made with Velocity. I mean that i logged once via Angular generated site, then authorize via spring security and then i can move over the sites which i have access.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspire you from what has been done in Jhipster https://jhipster.github.io/
You can even use it. Jhipster is a spring boot + angular generator. I often use it to inspire me and learn best practice.